# Unable to create a folder inside .zip file after reading the file data from list of attachments

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest, filereader

I am reading list of attachment files and then creating a zip file. Inside the zip file i am creating a folder with a name of 'Attachments' and storing all the attachments files. The following code used is for creating zip file with 'Attachment folder'. I have debugged and found that inside myBlob variable the data is present, the zip file is generated but the 'Attachment folder' is not there. Can someone tell me how to do it?

```
for (let i = 0; i < attachmentList.length; i++) {
  const attachment = attachmentList[i]
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('GET', attachment.url, true)
  xhr.responseType = 'blob'
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      const myBlob = this.response
      zip.file(`Attachments/${fileName}`, myBlob)
    }
  }
  xhr.send()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.blob()
            })
            zip.file(`Attachments/${fileName}`, data)
```